# How can I cast to subclass when using LINQ and TPT EF?

Tags: entity-framework, casting, ef-code-first

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class RealPeople { }

public class Users : RealPeople { }
public class People : RealPeople { }
```

In my dbContext, I defined a dbSet for `RealPeople` and on the OnModelCreating procedure, I specified separated tables for People and Users:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<People>().ToTable("People");
```

This creates the corresponding full hierarchy in my DB, with the 3 corresponding tables.
The problem comes when I want to retrieve the list of `Users` in my DB. 
This:

```
List = (from Reg in PersistentMgr.RealPeople select (Users)Reg)
       .ToList();
```

or this:

```
List = (from Reg in PersistentMgr.RealPeople select (Users)((RealPeople)Reg))
       .ToList();
```

Throws an exception:

> LINQ only being able to cast primitive model types.

So the thing is, I can't cast RealPeople to the corresponding subclass Users.
Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Past me: EF sucks. You should have moved to django sooner

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to get a collection of subclasses is using [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx#Y684):

```
var users = (from p in PersistentMgr.RealPeople select p).OfType<User>();
```

Comment: Slight optimization. Put the OfType right after setting the source so that the rest of the query uses the correct type instance. `var users = from p in PersistentMgr.RealPeople.OfType<User>() select p;`

Comment: Thanks! This seems performing and useful ie when a condition depends on a subclass field!

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
var list = PersistentMgr.RealPeople.Select(reg => reg as Users).ToList();
```

better:

```
var list = PersistentMgr.RealPeople.Select(reg => (reg is Users) ? reg as Users : null).ToList();
```

You will get the same error if you try this:

```
var realperson = new RealPeople();
var user = (Users) realperson;
```

The reason is because the compiler doesn't know how to convert complex types into their subtypes by simple casting - so you need to use the as keyword instead. This will either return null, or the supertype casted into the subtype.

```
var realperson = new RealPeople();
var user = realperson as Users; // user is realperson converted into a Users object
var aString = "this is a string";
var otheruser = aString as Users; // otheruser is null, because aString was not a valid supertype for Users
```

Comment: Amazingly, EF translates casts using the cast operator and the `as` operator differently. I couldn't believe it when I switched my code from cast to `as` and it started working. It wasn't exactly the problem that OP has, but your suggestion was key.